Greenhouse harvest API pagination doesn't work as expected
I'm working with greenhouse API and tried to work with some API and their pagination mechanism.
Most of their APIs worked as documented, but the "User Permissions" API pagination didn't work for me.
Does anyone familiar with that issue and have a soltution?
Reference: https://developers.greenhouse.io/harvest.html#user-permissions
This user have more than 100 results for this API.
response = requests.get('https://harvest.greenhouse.io/v1/users/1372428/permissions/jobs?page=1&per_page=100', auth=('api_key',''))
print(response.headers.get("link"))

Results:
'<https://harvest.greenhouse.io/v1/users/1372428/permissions/jobs?page=1&per_page=100&since_id=133383843>; rel="next"'

You can see from the results and the next page is the current page.

You can see from the code that I added that next page is the current page (page=1)

Yes. The copy paste didn't work well. Fixed it. But the issue remain
